# How do burst-fire sharpshooter weapons behave?

Tags: steamworld-heist

I just found a burst-fire sharpshooter weapon in a store. The whole point of sharpshooter weapons is being able to land one crucial shot from afar, so how do burst-fire sharpshooter weapons work? Do all shots follow the same path?

Would be interested in an answer before I invest 4000 water into buying it.

[image: Cranky's Delight (Rare)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found this video:

So it looks like all the shots indeed follow almost precisely the same path.